# Form Components went missing Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, text-editor

Was making a very simple text editor for practice, got the form all setup but then when I started to add the code all of the form components suddenly disappeared from the form but the still exist somewhere. Not really sure what is going on.

I have posted the code I have written so far. Alot of the features are likely going to be removed as I want this text editor to follow a free writing style. I really only plan to use the "File" drop down selection (New, Open, Save and Exit).

Thank in advance for any assistance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomTextEditor2 {
    public partial class TextEditor : Form {
        public TextEditor() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Editor and General
        #endregion

        #region MainMenu
        #endregion

        #region Toolbar
        #endregion

        #region contextmenu
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        #region file
        void New()
        {
            Document.Clear();
        }

        void Open()
        {
            if (openWork.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Document.LoadFile(openWork.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
        }

        void Save()
        {
            if (saveWork.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    Document.SaveFile(saveWork.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        void Exit()
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        #endregion

        #region edit
        #endregion

        #region tools

            void customise()
            {
                ColorDialog myDialog = new ColorDialog();
                if (myDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    mainMenu.BackColor = myDialog.Color;
                    Status.BackColor = myDialog.Color;
                    Tools.BackColor = myDialog.Color;
                }
            }

        #endregion

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Okay here is the code from TextEditor.Designer.cs:

```
namespace CustomTextEditor2
{
    partial class TextEditor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // TextEditor
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(732, 434);
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(748, 473);
            this.Name = "TextEditor";
            /this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.TextEditor_Load_1);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip mainMenu;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox Document;
        private System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip Status;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem mM_File;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem file_New;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem file_Open;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem file_Save;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem file_Exit;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel charCount;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel zoom;
        private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openWork;
        private System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog saveWork;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what "disappeared but still exist somewhere" means. Are you saying that the controls are still visible in Object Explorer but aren't being rendered on the form in Design View? Please try to describe the symptoms in precise terms.

Comment: Did you mess with the desigenr.cs file?

Comment: I meant that the controls must still exist because when I thought they had just been deleted and attempted to re-add them using the same names, I got a dialog box that said that such an object already exists with that name. Sorry for the cryptic explanation lol

Comment: I don't believe I had made any changes to the designer.cs file, I will upload the code just in case though.

Comment: Okay here is the code from TextEditor.Designer.cs: